# PrintWindow Flickering

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I'm trying to capture a window using the method I always used with PrintWindow

```
RECT rc;
GetClientRect(hwnd, out rc); //The process window handler

Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rc.right, rc.bottom, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
Graphics gfxBmp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
IntPtr hdcBitmap = gfxBmp.GetHdc();

PrintWindow(hwnd, hdcBitmap, 1);

gfxBmp.ReleaseHdc(hdcBitmap);
gfxBmp.Dispose();
bmp.Save("test.png");
```

The problem is that in this specific game process the window gets blank really fast when it calls the Printwindow function, so sometimes the image saved is totally white.

So I tried to use BitBlt:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rc.right, rc.bottom, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
Graphics gfxBmp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
IntPtr dest = gfxBmp.GetHdc();
IntPtr source = GetWindowDC(hwnd);

BitBlt(dest, 0, 0, rc.width, rc.height, source, 0, 0, 13369376);
bmp.Save("test.png");
```

But using the code above the image saved is totally black.

There is any way to prevent PrintWindow to make the process window to flick that "white layer" ? If it's nto possible BitBtl should solve that issue for me right? But what is wrong with my code?

Thank you

Comment: IS this winforms for WPF? in winforms you can just draw to an image and at the end just repaint the final image to the screen, essentially buffering the graphics. In WPF you can do the same thing but depending on what your trying to do there are different approaches. Like BitMapCahcedBrush lets you render directly from the hardware.

Comment: @noone392: The question is asking about capturing another application's window contents.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot successfully with some other tool, such as the Snipping Tool?

Comment: Look's like it's a issue with PrintWindow() on windows that are rendered using DirectX, that should be fixed using BitBlt, it's weird that I'm getting the black image when saving it, not sure what is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 3):

You could try with this code, it's working for me. If you still see black image, probably you have to go for DWM solution.

UPDATE: fixed missing window argument

```
    public Bitmap CaptureWindowImage(IntPtr hWnd, System.Drawing.Rectangle wndRect)
    {
        IntPtr hWndDc = GetDC(hWnd);
        IntPtr hMemDc = CreateCompatibleDC(hWndDc);
        IntPtr hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hWndDc, wndRect.Width, wndRect.Height);
        SelectObject(hMemDc, hBitmap);

        BitBlt(hMemDc, 0, 0, wndRect.Width, wndRect.Height, hWndDc, 0, 0, TernaryRasterOperations.SRCCOPY);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.FromHbitmap(hBitmap);

        DeleteObject(hBitmap);
        ReleaseDC(hWnd, hWndDc);
        ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, hMemDc);

        return bitmap;
    }

    private enum TernaryRasterOperations : uint
    {
        /// <summary>dest = source</summary>
        SRCCOPY = 0x00CC0020,
        /// <summary>dest = source OR dest</summary>
        SRCPAINT = 0x00EE0086,
        /// <summary>dest = source AND dest</summary>
        SRCAND = 0x008800C6,
        /// <summary>dest = source XOR dest</summary>
        SRCINVERT = 0x00660046,
        /// <summary>dest = source AND (NOT dest)</summary>
        SRCERASE = 0x00440328,
        /// <summary>dest = (NOT source)</summary>
        NOTSRCCOPY = 0x00330008,
        /// <summary>dest = (NOT src) AND (NOT dest)</summary>
        NOTSRCERASE = 0x001100A6,
        /// <summary>dest = (source AND pattern)</summary>
        MERGECOPY = 0x00C000CA,
        /// <summary>dest = (NOT source) OR dest</summary>
        MERGEPAINT = 0x00BB0226,
        /// <summary>dest = pattern</summary>
        PATCOPY = 0x00F00021,
        /// <summary>dest = DPSnoo</summary>
        PATPAINT = 0x00FB0A09,
        /// <summary>dest = pattern XOR dest</summary>
        PATINVERT = 0x005A0049,
        /// <summary>dest = (NOT dest)</summary>
        DSTINVERT = 0x00550009,
        /// <summary>dest = BLACK</summary>
        BLACKNESS = 0x00000042,
        /// <summary>dest = WHITE</summary>
        WHITENESS = 0x00FF0062
    }

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, PreserveSig = true, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hdc, IntPtr hgdiobj);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleBitmap(IntPtr hdc, int nWidth, int nHeight);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr hdc);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    private static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr CreateBitmap(int nWidth, int nHeight, uint cPlanes, uint cBitsPerPel, IntPtr lpvBits);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    private static extern bool BitBlt(IntPtr hdc, int nXDest, int nYDest, int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hdcSrc, int nXSrc, int nYSrc, TernaryRasterOperations dwRop);
```

Comment: what is the window object? Where is it initialized?

Comment: You're right @Franziee, I missed the window argument. Code updated!

Comment: I believe the window argument is still missing

Comment: @Luishg it should be ok now, it was a typo. Let me know.

Comment: @Francesco thanks, it is now! This was the only solution that actually worked for me. Others were getting me a blank/transparent screen.

Comment: Apparently this has a leak, calling this method a few thousand times (around 10k) the line "Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.FromHbitmap(hBitmap);" will throw a GDI generic error exception, only re-opening the application will allow it to run again until it reaches that limit once again. Have we missed to release/delete something in there?

Comment: @Luishg mmm don't know, maybe you are creating too many Bitmaps? The function CaptureWindowImage return a bitmap so it's your duty to handle all the instances you created (10k???) and deallocate them. I would suggest you to manage this using a pool or something.

Comment: A minor suggestion, use `System.Drawing.Size` instead of `System.Drawing.Rectangle` since in this example only `height` and `width` is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Francesco's answer almost worked, but there is a memory leak due to attempting to call `ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, hMemDc);` it will not leak if `DeleteDC(hMemDc);` is called.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-releasedc

> The application must call the ReleaseDC function for each call to the
>   GetWindowDC function and for each call to the GetDC function that
>   retrieves a common DC.
>
> An application cannot use the ReleaseDC function to release a DC that
>   was created by calling the ***CreateDC function; instead, it must use the
>   DeleteDC function.*** ReleaseDC must be called from the same thread that
>   called GetDC.

This was verified by the number of `GDI Objects` in taskmanager and also memory usage